# How import AdventureWorks to SQuirrel SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, squirrel-sql

I downloaded AdventureWorks 2012 from [Microsoft's sql-server-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks) but how to import the database (.mdf + .ldf) into SQuirrel SQL?

Comment: You need to **restore** the `.bak` file (if you have a `.bak` file), or you need to **attach** the `.mdf` to the SQL Server instance you're working with - then you can access the database from any front end tool

Comment: You need to install SQL Server before you can "import" that. Did you do that?

Comment: Installing SQL Server? On Linux???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQuirreL is not a database server. It is a querying tool that connects to a database server.

You need a copy of MS SQL Server installed on a Windows PC. Then you need to import Adventure Works into it.

Once you've done that you can connect using SQuirreL and the appropriate JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

You could restore the Adv Works database into SQL Server using SQuirreL from the command line.
There are some syntax examples at the Microsoft T-SQL reference site.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a `.bak` (MTF) file you can restore via SQuirrelSQL using the following T-SQL :

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2017
FROM DISK = '/path/to/AdventureWorks2017.bak'
WITH MOVE 'AdventureWorks2017' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/AdventureWorks2017.mdf',
MOVE 'AdventureWorks2017_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/AdventureWorks2017.ldf'
```

You'll have to adapt the file paths and possibly the names for the `MOVE` parts. I used:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '/path/to/AdventureWorks2017.bak'
```

to find the correct names.